# is it possible to store more than one value in the same session object if yes then tell me how through code .?

Tags: servlets

is it possible to use map to retrieve session object ?

```
         For Example: HTTPSession session=request.getSession();
          session.setAtrributes("Avr",atr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store multiple values in one session object you can use collections.Here is the code

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Test1");
names.add("Test2");

HTTPSession session=request.getSession();
session.setAtrribute("Avr",names);
```

When you get the value from session you need to cast it.

```
List<String> values = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("Avr");
```